# Помогите написать функцию 4**3 = 13 + 15 + 17 + 19 в python

Tags: python

Всем привет. Помогите написать функцию:

существует закономерность:

```
1^3 = 1; 
2^3 = 3 + 5; 
3^3 = 7 + 9 + 11;
4^3 = 13 + 15 + 17 + 19;
и т. д.
```

Надо создать функцию show_cube(n), которая
при вызове выводит соответствующую строку:
Например:
show_cube(3)
должна вывести:
3**3 = 7 + 9 + 11

show_cube(5)
должна вывести:
5**3 = 21 + 23 + 25 + 27 + 29 = 125

Comment: вам сумма последовательных нечетных чисел нужна что ли?

Comment: нет сама сумма не нужна, а надо чтобы при вызове функции n**3 выводилась такая строка:
3^3 = 7 + 9 + 11......
4^3 = 13 + 15 + 17 + 19......
5^3 = 21 + 23 + 25 + 27 + 29...... и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю зачем тут вообще питон?

сумма арифметической прогрессии -

```
S = (2a1 + d(n-1)) * n / 2
```

если нужны последовательные нечетные числа, то получаем

```
S = (2a1 + 2(n-1)) * n / 2 = (a1 + n - 1) * n
```

при этом надо разложить число `n^3`, а значит

```
n^3 = (a1 + n - 1) * n
```

откуда

```
n^2 = a1 + n - 1
```

и

```
a1 = n^2 - n + 1
```

т.е. первый член прогрессии найден (`n` - известен был)

И что - эту формулу надо на питоне закодить?!!!

Алгоритм:

1. вычислить `a1` из приведённой выше формулы
2. создать список из `n` элементов, содержащий числа `a1` и выше
3. вывести список поэлементно, используя в качестве разделителя `+`

**вариант 1** - простой

```
print(f"{n}^3 = ", end='')
print(*list(map(lambda x: n * n - n + 1 + x * 2, range(n))), sep=' + ')
```

**вариант 2** - используется высшая математика (интегральное и тензорное исчисления)

```
print(f"{n}^3 = ", end='')
print(*range(n * n - n + 1, n * n + n + 1, 2), sep=' + ')
```

**вариант 3** - утечка из Зоны 51

```
print(f"{n}^3 = {' + '.join(map(str, range(n * n - n + 1, n * n + n + 1, 2)))}")
```

Comment: да, надо на питоне. я понимаю, что может вопрос глупый, но как есть.

Comment: @method, а какие именно сложности и где возникают? т.е. где надо подсказать то?

Comment: после того как нашел а1 не получается задать функцию, чтоб мне выводило значения а1 + 2 до тех пор пока не будет равно сумме n^3

Comment: @method, а как вы делаете, покажите код

Comment: Мыслил я в таком ключе:
def get_sum(n):
    a1 = n * (n - 1) + 1
    return a1

def show_cube(n):
for i in range(get_sum(n), n**3, 2):
    print(i)

(сорри, я только начал учиться, не судите строго)

Comment: @method, сильно усложняете - см. в конце моего коммента варианты

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать и пробовать!